# sql: filter rows based on conditions

Tags: sql

How to write a sql query to return rows only the column value exceed at least 1% of the sum of the column, like

```
%sql select * from df1 where total_bytes>= 0.01*sum(total_bytes) order by total_bytes desc
```

But this gave me errors.

Comment: For future reference: Please don't just say "this gave me errors". Please include the error message as well.

Comment: Thanks! will do so in future questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to compute the sum of the `total_bytes` column:

```
select *
from df1
where total_bytes >= 0.01*(select sum(total_bytes) from df1)
order by total_bytes desc
```

Comment: Cannot mark correct now, will mark it when I am allowed to do so